# What was the Lawveres explanation of adjoint functors in terms of Hegelian Philosophy?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, higher-category-theory

I was contemplating asking this question on Philsophy.SE but felt it was better directed here as there are a dearth of category theorists there.

According to the wikipedia entry on [Categorical Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_logic):

> Lawvere's writings, sometimes couched in a philosophical jargon, isolated some of the basic concepts as adjoint functors (which he explained as 'objective' in a Hegelian sense, not without some justification).

What was the explanation or justification.

Comment: I assume you can find it (the justification) in his books. The book _Conceptual Mathematics_ may be a good start.

Comment: @Wong: I don't think he would want to scare aware would be conceptualists in an introductory book like that and aimed at high-school kids by dropping Hegelian terminology in it to sound cool...!

Comment: *Conceptual Mathematics*, as far as I recall, doesn't even describe adjoint functors.

Comment: I seem to remember reading that Lawvere also thought that category theory was in some way related to Maoism (of which he was an adherent).

Comment: Reminds me of a claim by Adrian Mathias that associated category theory with "dialectical materialism," i.e. Marxism. Marx frequently follows where Hegel leads. https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/segal.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is that the process of describing a collection of mathematical objects by constructing a theory, and the process of finding all mathematical objects satisfying a mathematical theory, are adjoint operations in a precise sense. The back and forth dialectic between the concrete objects on the one hand and abstract theories on the other then translates to applying these adjoint functors, and composing them, perhaps with further adjoints.

In "any serious field of study", Lawvere takes 'objective logic' to mean the construction of concepts necessary for that study, and 'subjective logic' to mean making inferences between statements in a theory, subjective in the sense that any inference is relative to its assumptions.

All this is described for example in Lawvere's article *Tools for the advancement of Objective Logic: Closed Categories and Toposes* (1994) in the conference proceedings volume

*The logical foundations of cognition*,
Vancouver Studies in Cognitive Science, edited by John Macnamara and Gonzalo E. Reyes